# iOS App that open .ibook file in iBook

Tags: ios, ibooks

My app will download some .ibook file to the iphone in the application support directory.
Now want to open this .ibook file using the iBook App by opening URL like 
 "itms-books://xxxxxxx"

My question is what should be the correct path for my .ibook file?

I used to access the local file within my app using the path "file://....".

In simulator case, it will be "file://localhost/Users/.../Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/5C67C211-6DC6-43A1-A25A-B1FBB4000C64/Library/Application%20Support/bookfolder/example.ibooks"

I simply append this to "itms-books://". Though iBook app is launched it's not opening my example.ibooks but bring me to book store.

Anyone can show me a simple example?

Comment: What do you mean by "what should be the correct path"?

Comment: I mean what should be the "xxxxxxx"

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** open *.ibook* in iBooks app.